# How to create a dropdown login, register and contact form

Tags: html, css, button, navbar, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown login, register and contact form for my navbar, but I don't know how to do it because I'm new to all this and I'm kind of in the dark here. Can anyone please help me to do so? I would really appreciate it. This is my navbar:
[image: This is my navbar]

As you can see, those are the dropdown buttons but they have no content.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li>INICIO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR</li>
    </nav> 

</header>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .menu {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none;
   background-color: #151515;
   }
  .menu li.with-arrow {
  padding: 35px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
   color: lightgray;
   font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  .menu li.with-arrow:after {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
   content: '\f107';
   display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  .menu li.with-arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   }
  .menu li.with-arrow:hover:after {
   transform: translate(-50%, 5px);
  }

 .menu li {
 padding: 35px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 5px;
 color: lightgray;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 }
.menu li:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 color: white;
  }
```

My CSS code is for the animation of the arrows.

Comment: You will need to create a <ul> if you want a dropdown and populate it with links such as register and login. Bootstrap have a greate site with documentation with examples. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

Answer (score 0):

im sorry if i cant provide a solid answer, i remember doing this a while back and when i googles it i found alot of good guides step by step guides with code u can use. You might tried that but thought worth me tion there are some good guides out there,
Hope that maybe helps abit untill someone shows up here with an actual solid answer that remember/knows how to do it. :)

Maybe try this:

```
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to search a little more, YouTube didn't work for me, I'll try Google.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I place the HTML? En which part of the code so it works for the 3 buttons I want to have a dropdown

Comment: Try in the div called drop down content!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap needs to be installed, as well as creating an .onclick event for the button of the drop down. It should look something like what I will post next.

Comment: I have bootstrap, I just need the knowledge for the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<div class="container">

<img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" 
class="logo">
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="menu">
<button onclick="OnClick()">Button for Drop Down</button>
      <a href="#">INICIO</a>
      <a href="#" class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</a>
      <a href ="#" class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</a>
      <a href ="#" class="with-arrow">INGRESAR</a>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
```

```
<!-- additionally, the OnClick() function needs to be controlled by 
javascript, by declaring a function called OnClick I added links instead of 
 list elements because that is how I do drop down menus. -->`
```